# How can I parse inner HTML by class name where html is assigned to a string variable in Angular 7/Typescript

Tags: html, angular, typescript

How can I get the inner text of span by class name ? Here adr_address variable is not a DOM element but a string.

```
var adr_address = '<span class="street-address">12 Stephenson Rd</span>, <span class="locality">Summertown</span>, <span class="region">TN</span> <span class="postal-code">38483-7005</span>, <span class="country-name">USA</span>';

var street-address = ??;
var locality = ??;
var region = ??;
var postal-code = ??;
var country-name = ??

console.log(street-address);
console.log(locality);
console.log(region);
console.log(postal-code);
console.log(country-name);
```

The output must be like this :

12 Stephenson Rd

Summertown

TX

38483-7005

USA

Comment: adr_address is not a DOM element but a string. You have to use regExp.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use DOM Parser

```
const parser = new DOMParser();
const doc = parser.parseFromString(htmlString, 'text/html');

__ now you can use query selectors on this doc __
```

Comment: How can I write jQuery on Angular 7 project

Comment: var locality = doc.getElementsByClassName('locality')[0].innerHTML.toString();

That worked for me.Thanks

Comment: Don't use jquery in angular. Today js can do all the things that jquery is famous about but in native code. Last comment you sent is one of the ways.

Answer (score 1):

You can use @ViewChild,
for example:

html:

```
<span #st class="street-address">12 Stephenson Rd</span>
```

ts:

```
 @ViewChild('st') st;

 ngAfterViewInit(): void {
 console.log(this.st.nativeElement.innerHTML);
```

}

Comment: Here adr_address variable is not a DOM element but a string

Comment: then try to use RegEx

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me finally:

```
var adr_address = '<span class="street-address">12 Stephenson Rd</span>, <span class="locality">Summertown</span>, <span class="region">TN</span> <span class="postal-code">38483-7005</span>, <span class="country-name">USA</span>';
const parser = new DOMParser();
const doc = parser.parseFromString(adr_address, 'text/html');

var locality = doc.getElementsByClassName('locality')[0].innerHTML.toString(); 
var street-address = doc.getElementsByClassName('street-address')[0].innerHTML.toString();
var region = doc.getElementsByClassName('region')[0].innerHTML.toString();
var postal-code = doc.getElementsByClassName('postal-code')[0].innerHTML.toString();
```